# C# MVC - namespace in multi controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want use AnotherController name in SomeController.
But, RoutePrefix Attribute is can only be declared by Controller level.

Prepare the following.

```
namespace KRSMART.Controllers
{
    public class SomeController : Controller
    {
        /* localhost:0000/Some/Index */

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        /* I want Url */
        /* localhost:0000/Another/Test */

        [Route("Another/Index")]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

It didn't work as I wanted it to.

I know I can create a new controller and do it, but I didn't want to.

I'd like to get some advice from you who are familiar with Route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` before default route register,

your `RegisterRoutes` function should be like,

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: “Default”,
        url: “{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```